# Wiring parallel TFT with ESP32

Tags: lcd, esp32, tft

I have this [Parallel LCD TFT](http://www.kumantech.com/kuman-uno-r3-35-tft-display-screen-with-sd-card-socket-for-arduino-mega-2560-board-module-sc3a_p0109.html). I want to connect it with an ESP32 (NodeMCU). I am using the [TFT_eSPI](https://github.com/Bodmer/TFT_eSPI) library.
In the TFT_eSPI documentation, it says that the connection should be as following:

```
// The ESP32 and TFT the pins used for testing are:
//#define TFT_CS   33  // Chip select control pin (library pulls permanently low
//#define TFT_DC   15  // Data Command control pin - use a pin in the range 0-31
//#define TFT_RST  32  // Reset pin, toggles on startup

//#define TFT_WR    4  // Write strobe control pin - use a pin in the range 0-31
//#define TFT_RD    2  // Read strobe control pin  - use a pin in the range 0-31    
//#define TFT_D0   12  // Must use pins in the range 0-31 for the data bus
//#define TFT_D1   13  // so a single register write sets/clears all bits.
//#define TFT_D2   26  // Pins can be randomly assigned, this does not affect
//#define TFT_D3   25  // TFT screen update performance.
//#define TFT_D4   17
//#define TFT_D5   16
//#define TFT_D6   27
//#define TFT_D7   14
```

P.S. My tft does not have DC PIN. So, I wired nothing to GPIO15

After I wired the TFT, the ESP32 stop responding to flash process. and obviously, it did not run anything(even if I flash it without the screen and then wiring it again)

My question is:

- What is the mistake did I do? How can I link this parallel LCD with ESP32

Comment: How did you wire the 5V pin of the display? When attached to an uno/mega2560 it gets power over this (and possibly the 3v3) pin.

Comment: DC is the same as RS (or `LCD_RS` on your board).

Comment: @LotPings External 5v power supply

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the Late reply, I had the same issue.
You cant have anything connected to pin 15 or 2 during flash